# Spring MVC configuration throws weird exception

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to deploy a new spring MVC app, I've done it a dozen times, but now I run on a really weird error, can't even figure out what's happening:

1. My javaee-api is conflicting with the servlet-api. In the console it writes:

   ```
      INFO: validateJarFile(E:\development\workspace\conference\src\main\webapp\WEB-    INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2.
      Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
   ```

Well, yes, it is a warning, but this jar is not loaded and I need it. Also, I have no servlet-api jars in my application libs, etc.

1. Also, the console throws such an exception:

   ```
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
   ```

I mean, this jar is refered to the JSF and all of that stuff. I'm not using it at all, where should it try to get such a class? O_o

I am running the app on tomcat 7

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with jar file is that Tomcat's classloader validates all clases, that it loads to JVM. In your case it faced a class from servlets API - `javax.servlet.Servlet`. You application code **must not contain** such classes inside `WEB-INF/lib`. These classes are shipped with servlet container itself. If you use maven, just change the scope of `javax.servlet:servlet-api` to `provided`.

After you fix this, try to reload the whole app, because it may occur that classloader just blocked `javaee-api-6.0.jar` entirely, not allowing any other classes be loaded from it.

Comment: I don't have such class im my application. The reason I added the javaee-api is that in the application context while configuring the `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver` it threw such exception: `Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for javax/servlet/ServletContext`

Comment: This class is present in result war, under `WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar`. It is not ok. And you *build path* has nothing to do with *runtime*. You only need this class while building. I mean, not in the result war (runtime). So, what build system do you use? Maven?

Comment: Yeah, maven. I've just changed the scope of javaee-api to `provided` - it still throws the same exception.

Comment: And running app from the eclipse? Is you project configured as Web Project? Do you have any configured servers in workspace? Are they attached to the project? Did you try to clean the server?

Comment: I did clean all of the tmp. I run the project from direct web container (Tomcat), no IDEs. It is configured as a maven project.

Comment: Well, I used this way of jars config before, I really have no clue, why isn't it working now.

Comment: I've run out of ideas too, sorry :(

Comment: Thank you, anyways. :) If I figure it out - I will post as an edit over here. Glad to see a slavic bro over here :)

Comment: May the Force be with you!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `javaee-api-6.0.jar` file from your webapps' WEB-INF/lib directory, by setting the scope `provided` in its dependency.

The Spec refers that the Servlet Container (Here, Tomcat) will supply the implementation classes of the Java EE spec. Having application specific implementations is a stability and security problem that is disallowed by the spec/Tomcat.

Thanks!

Comment: I've already done that. The problem was that somehow that jar was getting to the runtime, but not just the compliation time. Total reconfiguration of the jars from the first time helped.